# How to use jQuery ajax to edit the text?

Tags: jquery

How to use form submit and ajax to edit the text Name & Sex ??
When I click first submit button it only change the first Name & Sex
If click second one just change the second Name & Sex !
How to do it ?

HTMl & JS

```
<!-- Form1 -->
<form action="index.php" class="form_edit" >
    Name: <span class="display">Tom</span><br>
    Sex: <span class="display_sex">Male</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="sex" value="" /><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
</form>
<!-- Form2 -->
<form action="index.php" class="form_edit" >
    Name: <span class="display">Mary</span><br>
    Sex: <span class="display_sex">Female</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="sex" value="" /><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
</form>
<!-- Form3 -->
<form action="index.php" class="form_edit" >
    Name: <span class="display">John</span><br>
    Sex: <span class="display_sex">Male</span><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="sex" value="" /><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.form_edit').submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "edit.php",
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
                $('.display').text(data);

            }
         });
        return false;
    }); 
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST['name']){

    $return = '{"name":"' . $_POST['name'] . '"}';
    echo $return;

}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. every form has only one submit button but u r saying something about second button. and here u have only name and u r talking about first name and second name.

Comment: Do you _want_ to affect the form that sent the ajax, and you are affecting all three?

Comment: Just edit the name & sex by the input eg.Name:Tom ,when I type Peter and the first name will change from Tom to Peter, not change Mary and others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a proper context to the jQuery selector inside the success handler. This way, it affects all elements with the class `display`.

```
$('.form_edit').submit(function(){
    var form = this; // <<< added
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "edit.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
            form.find('.display').text(data); // <<< modified

        }
     });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I try it before, but nothing have change !

Comment: this should only target the .display element in the form that was submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try the following code?

```
$('.form_edit').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "edit.php",
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
            $('.display').text(data);

        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Changing `return false` to `e.preventDefault()` does not fix anything, as `return false` does prevent the default action.